# Getting Multiple Items from AWS EC2 Metadata Link-Local Address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, request, command-line-interface

I am trying to retrieve multiple items from the AWS EC2 [link local address](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html)

It can be done using multiple calls to the link-local address:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
i-1234567890abcdef0

[ec2-user ~]$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-type
p3.2xlarge
```

These kind of calls are throteled by AWS

**Is there a way to make a single call to get both?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve both info by making a request to the [Instance identity document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-identity-documents.html#Retrieve%20the%20plaintext%20instance%20identity%20document%20Retrieve%20the%20plaintext%20instance%20identity%20document%20Retrieve%20the%20plaintext%20instance%20identity%20document).

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document
```

This will return a JSON that looks like this:

```json
{
    "devpayProductCodes" : null,
    "marketplaceProductCodes" : [ "1abc2defghijklm3nopqrs4tu" ], 
    "availabilityZone" : "us-west-2b",
    "privateIp" : "10.158.112.84",
    "version" : "2017-09-30",
    "instanceId" : "i-1234567890abcdef0",
    "billingProducts" : null,
    "instanceType" : "t2.micro",
    "accountId" : "123456789012",
    "imageId" : "ami-5fb8c835",
    "pendingTime" : "2016-11-19T16:32:11Z",
    "architecture" : "x86_64",
    "kernelId" : null,
    "ramdiskId" : null,
    "region" : "us-west-2"
}
```

Comment: is the two curls by mistake?